# Xampp SQL server 2014 PHP 7.1.9

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo un xampp corriendo con PHP 7.1.9. Utilizo el sql server 2014.

Pero ahora necesito los controladores para PHP. Sólo puedo encontrar una versión que soporta 5.5, 5.6 ...

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx)

¿Hay una manera de dejar que esto funcione con PHP 7.1.9?

Answer (score 1):

No hay opción para cambiar la version de PHP en XAMPP.

XAMPP está codificado con una versión específica de PHP para asegurarse de que todos los módulos son compatibles y funcionan correctamente.

Sin embargo, si tu proyecto necesita PHP 5.6, sólo tienes que instalar una versión anterior de XAMPP con PHP 5.6 empaquetado en él.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que utilizar `PDO` sin la necesidad de los driver para php
utilizando la siguiente cadena de connecction:

```
$Server='Miservidor';
$Database='Mibasedatos';
$Uid='usuename';
$Pwd='contraseña';
$conn = new PDO('odbc:Driver=;Server='.$Server.';Database='.$Database.';Uid='.$Uid.';Pwd='.$Pwd.';');
```